# es6 filter an array of objects by an array of filter objects

Tags: javascript, filter

given the following structure:

```
let filteredTasks = [
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'nope', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'started', other: false}
]
```

and:

```
let availableFilters = [{status: 'done'}, {other: false}]
```

how can I filter this array to get the following results:

```
filteredTasks =
[{status: 'done', other: false}, {status: 'done', other: false}]
```

my thoughts and attempts:

```
let filteredTasks = [
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'nope', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'started', other: false}
]

let availableFilters = [{status: 'done'}, {other: false}]

let filteredTasksList = availableFilters.map(item => {
    return runFilter(item)
})

function runFilter(currentFilter) {
  return filteredTasks.filter(item => {
    for (var key in currentFilter) {
        if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] !== currentFilter[key])
        return false
    }
    return true;
  })
}
```

...but obviously this is overriding each pass.

As always any feedback and help is greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance.

EDIT:
accepted the initial comment as the solution as it fits my needs.  I used that to take it a step further:

```
let filterTaskList = (list, filters) => {
  let entries = Object.entries(Object.assign(...filters))
  return list.filter(task => {
    return entries.every(([key, val]) => {
      return task[key] === val
     })
  })
}
```

Comment: Is every separate object in availableFilters supposed to represent a key->value match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a single object of the filters and take the entries for filtering.

```js
let filteredTasks = [
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'nope', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'started', other: false}
],
 availableFilters = [{status: 'done'}, {other: false}], // your filters
  filters = Object.entries(Object.assign(...availableFilters)), // returns an array of the filter's own enumerable property
  result = filteredTasks.filter(o => filters.every(([k, v]) => o[k] === v)); // .every returns true, when every item is fulfilling the condition
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if filteredTasks object are like this `{value: {status: 'done', other: true}}` and availableFilters  should be `[{value: {status: 'done'}}, {value:{other: false}}]` Can it work like this also?

Comment: I'm guessing `o[k] === v` should be replaced with deep equal

Comment: it depends if you have more properties in the first level or if the first level is a constant value. if you have a dynamic properties, you need to get all nested entries and take this for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Code first:

```js
let filteredTasks = [
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'nope', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: true},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'done', other: false},
  {status: 'started', other: false}
]

let availableFilters = [{status: 'done'}, {other: false}]

const matchesFilter = (filter, item) => Object.entries(filter).every(([key, value]) => item[key] === value)

function withFilters (filters) {
  return item => filters.every(f => matchesFilter(f, item))
}

console.log(filteredTasks.filter(withFilters(availableFilters)))
```

Explanation: the two interesting functions here are `matchesFilter` and `withFilters`.

`matchesFilter`: takes an object, the `filter` and compares every key/value to the `item` to ensure it matches.

`withFilters` takes in a list of filters and returns a function that can be used with `Array.prototype.filter` to produce a filtered list.

You then just use `withFilters(availableFilters)` as your filter function. You can even save that result to re-use it later.

```
let filterByAvailable = withFilters(availableFilters)
let availableTaks = filteredTasks.filter(filterByAvailable)
```